# MySQL combined result from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

this is my situation:

i have two tables A and B and want to combine the results from A and B.
probably with word is complicated to explain but using table result to illustrate it is more simple to understand.

**Code for table A**

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id_doc_a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject_a` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_nr_a` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `doc_type_a` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_date_a` date NOT NULL,
  `value_IN` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_doc_a`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Code for table B**

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `id_doc_b` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject_b` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_nr_b` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `doc_type_b` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_date_b` date NOT NULL,
  `value_OUT` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_doc_b`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to select all subjects_a and subjects_b with value (ex. JOHN) and combine in a single table with columns:

```
| SUBJECT | DOC_NR | DOC_TYPE | DOC_DATE    | TBL_A_VALUE_IN | TBL_B_VALUE_OUT |
|---------|--------|----------|-------------|----------------|-----------------|
| JOHN    | 1      | PDF      | 20018-03-16 | 50.00          | NULL OR 0.00    |
| JOHN    | 33     | PDF      | 20018-08-09 | 25.00          | NULL OR 0.00    |
| JOHN    | 13     | PDF      | 20018-07-29 | 32.50          | NULL OR 0.00    |
| JOHN    | 4      | PDF      | 20018-06-06 | 41.30          | NULL OR 0.00    |
| JOHN    | 12     | JPEG     | 20018-04-22 | NULL OR 0.00   | 78.20           |
| JOHN    | 31     | JPEG     | 20018-03-21 | NULL OR 0.00   | 6.50            |
| JOHN    | 33     | JPEG     | 20018-05-01 | NULL OR 0.00   | 26.99           |
```

where the first 4 rows are the result from Table A and the last 3 rows are result of Table B where the condition is SUBJECT (subject_a = subject_b) = JOHN.

Hope to have explained well, thanks for the help.

---

**Solution: Thanks to [@scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge)**

```
 SELECT 
     t.SUBJECT_NAME, 
     t.DOCUMENT_NR, 
     t.DOCUMENT_TYPE, 
     t.DOCUMENT_DATE, 
     t.TBL_A_VALUE_IN, 
     t.TBL_B_VALUE_OUT
FROM (
     SELECT 
           SUBJECT_a AS SUBJECT_NAME, 
           DOC_NR_a AS DOCUMENT_NR, 
           DOC_TYPE_a AS DOCUMENT_TYPE, 
           DOC_DATE_a AS DOCUMENT_DATE,
           VALUE_IN AS TBL_A_VALUE_IN, 
           NULL AS TBL_B_VALUE_OUT
     FROM a 
  UNION ALL
     SELECT  
           SUBJECT_b AS SUBJECT_NAME, 
           DOC_NR_b AS DOCUMENT_NR, 
           DOC_TYPE_b AS DOCUMENT_TYPE, 
           DOC_DATE_b AS DOCUMENT_DATE,
           NULL AS TBL_A_VALUE_IN,
           VALUE_OUT AS TBL_B_VALUE_OUT
     FROM b
) T 
  WHERE t.SUBJECT_NAME = 'john'
  ORDER BY t.DOCUMENT_DATE
```

i removed 0 tab_order and 1 and use aliases so it can be more readable.
For order can be used one of the columns on the first select and to add more condition's just use AND or if dont need NULL we can use 0.00 AS instead of NULL AS in both selects.

Thanks again to scaisEdge for help and patience.

Comment: If you know that you can use a `JOIN` (since you mention it in the tags), why don't you just go ahead and do the query yourself, or at least try to?

Comment: thanks but for sure i'm not here to ask without try before and readings guides but from what i read may be it can be done using join, or union, or union with inner join and sincerly i was a little lost so thats why i use that tag. if you want to help, you are welcome if not... welcome anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use UNION ALL

```
   select   t.SUBJECT, t.DOC_NR, t.DOC_TYPE, t.DOC_DATE 
       , t.TBL_B_VALUE_IN,t.TBL_B_VALUE_OUT
    from (

    select   SUBJECT_a subject, DOC_NR_a DOC_NR, DOC_TYPE_a DOC_TYPE, DOC_DATE_a  DOC_DATE
         , VALUE_IN TBL_B_VALUE_IN, null TBL_B_VALUE_OUT , 0 tab_order 
    from table_a 
    union all
    select   SUBJECT_b, DOC_NR_b, DOC_TYPE_b, DOC_DATE_b , null,VALUE_OUT , 1  
    from table_b
    ) T 
    order by t.tab_order
```

Comment: this seems not to work, there are 3 selects, select 1 and select 2 inside FROM with union all SELECT on table b
what values are refered by select 1, select 2 because exactly as it is is not working on my side. Thanks in advance

Comment: @sigma  ..what   mean "seems  not work" .. you have error ?  show me the exatc error message  .. wrong result ? show me the actual result and the expected  result  ...    ..

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'SUBJECT' in 'field list'
the expected result is like on the first post, normally i expect to have for example: from table a i have 4 result, from table B i have 2 results and the total table must have 4+2 rows where the first 4 rows have in column VALUE_IN not null values and in column VALUE_OUT null results, same situation from other 3 rows, they have in 4 first rows null values and in last two have values.

Comment: answer updated..  but subject should be the column name from both table_a and table_b  ..you have each column iwth different  suffix

Comment: you have doc_nr_b in table_a  is the uniqe with suffix b ..  is strange  .. in my query have used  doc_nr_a  .. eventually change with column name you need

Comment: Yes it was my mistake when typing, in table A it should be doc_nr_a, i corrected it on my db too and trying to execute the updated query is giving me Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 't.SUBJECT' in 'field list'

Comment: this is the query i execute:
SELECT   t.SUBJECT, t.DOC_NR, t.DOC_TYPE, t.DOC_DATE 
     , t.TBL_B_VALUE_IN,t.TBL_B_VALUE_OUT
  FROM (

  SELECT   subject_a, doc_nr_a, doc_type_a, doc_date_a 
       , value_IN TBL_B_VALUE_IN, NULL TBL_B_VALUE_OUT , 0 tab_order 
  FROM table_a 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT   subject_b, doc_nr_b, doc_type_b, doc_date_b , NULL,value_OUT , 1  
  FROM table_b
  ) t 
  ORDER BY t.tab_order

Comment: answer  updated .. missing the right column alias  .

Comment: Thanks...Grazie mille :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just JOIN the tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
    JOIN B on A.subject_a = B.subject_b
WHERE A.subject_a = 'JOHN'
```

That will combine both datasets into one result table. Of course, if you don't want duplicate values (i.e. id_doc_a and id_doc_b) you can specify which ones you want instead of the wildcard *

Comment: this is not the requested result i ask but anyway thanks for helping